Voltage: work to move a charge, or difference of electric potential?
Let's say I have a single positive charge inside of an electrostatic field. I want to move this charge from point A to point B and determine the voltage between the two points.
Points A and B are the same distance from the negative charge producing the electrostatic field. The charge is initially at rest at point A, and will be at rest at point B.

Wikipedia gives two definitions for voltage:
"the difference in electric potential between two points" (1), and
"the work needed per unit of charge to move a positive test charge from the first point to the second point" (2).
According to definition 1, the voltage should be zero; there is no difference between the electric potential at point A and B, as it is the same distance away from the negative charge producing the field.
According to definition 2, the voltage should be positive; it will take work to move the positive charge from point A to point B, as I must counteract the vertical component of the electric force and so on.
I am assuming both definitions are correct. Why is the result different between the two definitions?

You just computed (2) wrong. You are not moving in the vertical direction and so the force in the vertical direction contributes no work done at all. You can also choose a trajectory that is the circular arc centred on the negative charge and immediately see that there is no discrepancy.

The line integral is independent of the path chosen.


it will take work to move the positive charge from point A to point B, as I must counteract the vertical component of the electric force and so on.

You are quite correct that the distance to the negative charge changes as you move, but the total work done is still zero.

As you move from A to C along the dashed line the PE decreases and you get work out of the system. For example if the dashed line was a track and the charged object was a ball rolling along the track the ball would accelerate as it moved from A to C. The decrease in the potential energy would be converted to an increase in kinetic energy.
Then as you move from C to B you need to put in work to increase the distance from the negative charge. In our example of the ball on the track the ball would decelerate as its kinetic energy was turned back into potential energy.
The work we get out moving from A to C is equal and opposite to the work we have to put in to move the ball from C to B, so when we add them to get the total work we find it is zero.
So your second definition for the potential energy change is fine, but it should read:

the total work needed per unit of charge to move a positive test charge from the first point to the second point


In the diagram below the red dashed circle with the negative charge at its centre is an equipotential with the electric field lines produced by the negative charge at right angles to the circle.

As the field is conservative the work done in moving between any two points is independent of the path taken.
In this case the simplest paths to consider are the "top" portion of the circle between positions $A$ and $B$ and the "bottom" portion f the circle between positions $A$ and $B$.
In both cases the work done is zero.
Your black dashed path $\Delta x$ has symmetry and the negative external work done in going a distance $\Delta x/2$ from $A$ is equal in magnitude to the positive external work done in going a distance $\Delta x/2$ to $B$, ie the net external work done is zero.
